# Java EE 6 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I am new to Java EE 6 and am following the [Java EE 6 tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5x7SZRX8_po). I have created a Java EE 6 project with contexts and DI enabled.

I am getting the following error:

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lboundaries/UsersFacade;**

Environment: Netbeans 7.3, JDK 1.6 and Glassfish3.1.2. Please advise me on resolving the issue.

(a) web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

(b) beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

</beans>
```

(c) Entity Bean from Database, Users (package name : entitites in users-ejb)

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author abc
 */
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "", schema = "USER")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUserid", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.userid = :userid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUseridPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.userid = :userid AND u.password=:password"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUsername", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.username = :username"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByEnabled", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.enabled = :enabled")})
public class Users implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer userid;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(length = 30)
    private String username;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(length = 30)
    private String password;
    @Size(max = 1)
    @Column(length = 1)
    private String enabled;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(Integer userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public Integer getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(Integer userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(String enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (userid != null ? userid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Users)) {
            return false;
        }
        Users other = (Users) object;
        if ((this.userid == null && other.userid != null) || (this.userid != null && !this.userid.equals(other.userid))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entities.Users[ userid=" + userid + " ]";
    }

}
```

(d) Session Bean for entity bean, UsersFacade (package name : boundaries in users-ejb)
has method :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package boundaries;

import entities.Users;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author abc
 */
@Stateless
public class UsersFacade extends AbstractFacade<Users> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "sbg-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public UsersFacade() {
        super(Users.class);
    }

    public Users validUser(String username, String password) {
        Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Users.findByUseridPassword").setParameter("username", username).setParameter("password", password);
        Users user = (Users) query.getSingleResult();
        return user;
    }
}
```

(e) created JSF Managed Bean, LoginBean (package name : com.users in users-war)

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.xyz;

import boundaries.UsersFacade;
import entities.Users;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author abc
 */
@Named(value = "loginBean")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {

    @EJB
    private UsersFacade usersFacade;
    private Users currentUser;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of LoginBean
     */
    public LoginBean() {
    }


    /**
     * @param currentUser the currentUser to set
     */
    public void setCurrentUser(Users currentUser) {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    /**
     * @return the currentUser
     */
    public Users getCurrentUser() {
        if(currentUser==null){
            currentUser= new Users();
        }
        return currentUser;
    }

    public String validUser(){
        String outcome="index?faces-redirect=true";
        Users user=usersFacade.validUser(getCurrentUser().getUsername(), getCurrentUser().getPassword());
        if(user!=null){
            outcome="/view/home?faces-redirect=true";
        }else{
            System.out.println("Unable to find User with User Id:"+getCurrentUser().getUsername()+"!");
        }
        return outcome;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the classpath too

Issue-java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Root Cause: Incorrect Java path set in Environment Variable Section

Solution: Set correct JAVA_HOME Path

Steps->Environment Variable Setting (My Comp-Right Click ->Properties->Env Variable->Advance Tab ->Variable)

Create new JAVA_HOME Environment Variable.

JAVA_HOME .;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_14

Set JAVA_HOME variable in PATH Variable section.

PATH %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Set JAVA_HOME variable in CLASSPATH Variable

CLASSPATH %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib

Restart System

Verify all variable

echo %CLASSPATH%

echo %JAVA_HOME%

echo %PATH%

Compile & Run the program